# Migrate Gulp .src to Webpack entry import

Tags: node.js, webpack, gulp

I am migrating from Gulp to Webpack and I am facing following issue:

In Gulp I have this task to :

```js
// gulpfile.js
let sources = {
    js: {
        coffee: [
            'src/MainClass.coffee',
            'src/**/*Module.coffee',
            'src/**/*.coffee',
            '!src/**/*.coffee',
        ]
    }
};

task('build-scripts', function () {
    return gulp
        .src(sources.js.coffee)
        .pipe(coffee({bare: true})
        .pipe(dest('dest'));
});
```

As you can see I have specified order of files concatenation: first MainClass, than any module, and finally anything else except for files starting with `_`.

How to achieve this?

I have tried following Webpack approach with `glob`, but it just lists files, not in my preferred way:

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: {
            import: glob.sync(sources.js.coffee),
            dependOn: 'vendor',
            filename: 'app.js'
        },
    },
};
```

---

`glob` gives me wrong list:

```bash
src/Abc.coffee
src/AnotherClass.coffee
src/MainClass.coffee
src/SomeModule.coffee
src/foo/bar/ZarClass.coffee
```